# Implementing MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, netbeans

I am working on implementing code using MVC for my class however I am running into an error I cant seem to figure out. The only parts of the assignment I am supposed to change are Model, View, and Controller so the rest of the classes were already completed for us.

When I run the code I get an error in the controller saying:

"error: incompatible types: Student cannot be converted to String
        view.DisplayOnButton(model.getInfoForStudent(0), 0);"

How do I fix this?

Here is what I have:

Controller -

```
public class Controller
    {
    Model model;
    View view;

    public Controller(Model model, View view)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
        SetViewFromModel();
    }

    public void SetViewFromModel()
    {
        view.DisplayOnButton(model.getInfoForStudent(0), 0);
        view.DisplayOnButton(model.getInfoForStudent(1), 1);
        view.DisplayOnButton(model.getInfoForStudent(2), 2);
    }
    }
```

Model -

```
    public class Model
    {
    ArrayList<Student> sts = new ArrayList<>();

    public Model()
    {
        //creates 3 students
        MailAddress addr1 = new MailAddress("107 W College Avenue", "State College", "PA", 16801);
        Student st1 = new Student("Emily", "Smith", 20, addr1);
        MailAddress addr2 = new MailAddress("200 W College Avenue", "State College", "PA", 16801);
        Student st2 = new Student("Mary", "Doe", 20, addr2);
        MailAddress addr3 = new MailAddress("300 W College Avenue", "State College", "PA", 16801);
        Student st3 = new Student("John", "Doe", 20, addr3);
        //add them to the array of students
        sts.add(st1);
        sts.add(st2);
        sts.add(st3);        
    }

    public Student getInfoForStudent (int studentIndex)
        {
            return sts.get(studentIndex);
        }  
}
```

View -

```
public void DisplayOnButton(String infoToDisplay, int onButton)
    {
        mf.getIp().DisplayOnButton(infoToDisplay, onButton);
    }
```

Comment: can you put your stacktrace (the error that you get)? there you should have the information about the line that caused the error

Comment: Call toString() on student objects? But please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Your question is missing various details we would need to help you.

Comment: `DisplayOnButton` has a requirement that the parameter must be a `String`, either change the parameter type or pass in a `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method `DisplayOnButton` is expecting a String and you are passing an Student, you will have to convert your `getInfoForStudent` to return a String or convert the Student to String.

I recommend you to overwrite toString() for your mail and student so it creates an String with the information that you expect.

for example:

```
public class Student {
private final String name;
private final String surname;
private final int age;
private final MailAddress mailAddress;

public Student(String name, String surname, int age, MailAddress mailAddress) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.mailAddress=mailAddress;
}

 @Override
public String toString() {

    return String.format("name: %s surname:%s age:%d mail address:%s", name, surname, age, mailAddress);
}
}
```

you will have to do something similar for mailAddress, so then your `getInfoForStudent` looks like that:

```
 public String getInfoForStudent (int studentIndex)
    {
        return sts.get(studentIndex).toString();
    }
```

Comment: this getInfo() is the toString(), so you can change `return sts.get(studentIndex)` to `return sts.get(studentIndex).getInfo()`

Comment: The Student class is already completed for us in this assignment and its done in a similar fashion as you have it and returns a String. when I try `return sts.get(studentIndex).getInfo()` I get an error next to the line of code saying "String cannot be converted to student"

Comment: so use this method to get a String with the information of your Students